# Pair of two-variable polynomial equations of high order

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, st.statistics, na.numerical-analysis, polynomials, estimation-theory

I have the following pair of equations to be solved for two variables $\rho$ and $D$ resulting from a certain Maximum Likelihood Estimation for a time series $X_n > 0$, $n=0, \ldots, N+1$ with $N \ge 1$:

$$ \sum\limits_{n=0}^N \frac{1}{\rho + D X_n^2} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^N \frac{(X_{n+1}-X_n)^2}{(\rho + D X_n^2)^2}$$

$$ \sum\limits_{n=0}^N \frac{X_n^2}{\rho + D X_n^2} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^N \frac{X_n^2(X_{n+1}-X_n)^2}{(\rho + D X_n^2)^2}$$

Specifically I'm interested in a positive solution, which should be unique (I think)...

The problem is apparently equivalent to solving a pair of polynomial equations of order $2N-1$, but I was hoping there might be a "trick" or a way to obtain an analytical solution due to its form? I've tried some changes of variables and integral transforms, but with no luck... I'm sure there's a smarter way to analyze the equations, which I will do, but I'm hoping the smartest way is to ask here ;)

One random observation is that $\partial_D(\text{first eq}) = \partial_\rho(\text{secondeq})$. I have absolutely no idea if this is useful.

Also, what would be the best scheme for solving equations such as this one numerically? I use mostly Python and the tools in [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) will probably be helpful, but I'd appreciate some further tips! Maybe an OLS scheme for the equations?

EDIT:I should probably mention that setting $D=0$ and forgetting about the second equation gives the solution $\rho = \frac{1} {N+1} \sum (X_{n+1}-X_n)^2 $.

Comment: Should the sum on the right end at n=N-1? Or is $X_{N+1}=X_0$?

Comment: Oops.. fixed the series definition (although the boundary condition would make sense too).

Comment: Letting $N=0$, it seems that $\rho+DX_0^2=(X_1-X_0)^2$, which does not have a unique positive solution for $\rho$ and $D$.

Comment: Oops 2... $N$ needs to be larger than zero (edited the question)!

Comment: $\rho=+\infty$, $D=0$ "solves" the system :-)

Comment: Indeed, suvrit, although that's not exactly the solution I was looking for ;-) Actually that's also a useful observation, since that's where my numerical solutions usually tend to...

Comment: as $\rho \to \infty$, the rhs goes faster to $0$ than the lhs, so there might still be something here; though the setup with $X_n$ being a constant sequence defeats that. If we assume that the $X_n$ are distinct, that might help, but it seems that the system is still not immune to a trivial "solution"